# Ruby - Running an iteration by calling require 'filename'

Tags: ruby, count, iteration

I had a thought and so far the thought has failed so I wanted to share it and have it corrected.

I have a series of Ruby scripts written to walk through a ecommerce site from adding to cart to checking out.  The scripts are all referencing each other in order to keep the chain moving along.  What I want to do is make a Ruby file called Run_CheckOut.rb but be able to run through several iterations of the checkout by invoking this file x amount of times.

Here was my first try:

```
i = 0
10.times do 
  i+= 1
  puts "Iteration number: " + i.to_s
  require 'Test_OrderService_SubmitCart'
end
```

When I do this it will only call the required file once but continues to count for i.  How can I call the required file 10 times or am I completely off base with this?

Comment: just to let you know, `10.times do |i|` will allow you to use `i` inside the loop, starting at 0 and going through 9. (The inside of your loop will operate the same, but then you don't need to declare the `i` outside the loop.)

Answer (score 4):

> am I completely off base with this?

Yes.

> What I want to do is make a Ruby file called Run_CheckOut.rb but be able to run through several iterations of the checkout by invoking this file x amount of times.

The point of `require` is to make code available to your execution environment. `require` only pulls in the code once -- calling it again has no effect. `load` will run the included script each time, but that is a poor design choice.

What you want is to invoke something in the source code file. Perhaps you'd like to call a method, or create an object from a class. Define a method:

```
def do_something
  # blah blah
end
```

require the file at the top of your script:

```
require 'Test_OrderService_SubmitCart'
```

and invoke the method in the loop:

```
i = 0
10.times do 
  i+= 1
  puts "Iteration number: " + i.to_s
  do_something
end
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.

Comment: It is for a single script.  I'm looking for a way to globally trigger several scripts with dependencies and run iterations of the scripts.  There may just be a complete design flaw with how I set this up.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `load` (note that you need to append `.rb`):

```
load 'Test_OrderService_SubmitCart.rb'
```

Contrary to `load`, `require` executes a source file **only once**. See the detailed description of what `require` does in the [reference documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005941).

Comment: `load` will tell Ruby to reload the file each time, but that only fixes a small problem in what is a bad programming practice. Reloading the file to cause code to run repeatedly is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a ruby convention for naming files and methods - lowercased and underscored.
Class and Module names are camel cased. These two conventions are never mixed.

Your final code should look something more like:

```
require 'order_service'
10.times do |n|
  puts "iteration #{n}"
  submit_cart
end
```

Notice the beauty.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree but my boss asked that I use camel case since I work in a .net shop.  It's not up to me but thanks for the info.